# Windows 2012: edit task after computer has been renamed?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

**Initial situation**

We set up a Windows 2012 R2 Session that will be used as a template for installations at our customer's locations. The prepared session contains a set of planned tasks that start programs with certain delays based on a number of parameters that are individual for each customer. The scripts all work fine on the template session.

**Problem**

As soon as a new server based on the template is set up, the computer has to be renamed to fit into the customer's network. After changing the computer name, there is no way to edit any of the predefined tasks, the task can be opened but as soon as I click "OK" to save any changes, a popup window is displayed with message:

```
An error has occurred for task EOC. Error message: The specified account name is not valid.
```

The problem seems to be that the author of the task contains the old computer name and thus Windows thinks that an unauthorized user tries to alter the given task.

[image: Error on task save]

Has anyone found a solution to the above problem?

Comment: Are you able to export the tasks? This will produce an XML file. You should be able to edit the XML to change the author and runas values and then import the task XML.

Comment: @jscott could you write your comment as an answer? Your way works good, I removed the host part from the author name, imported the XML again, renamed the computer and it's still editible. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a task's export option to create XML files. These files can be edited to modify the author and runas values. You then import the XML files to create tasks with the new values.

Answer (score 0):

The author will be based in the domain/workgroup which the template was created in, which could cause a conflict like this.
Was the tasks created by a domain user?
If yes, then try to create them with a local user, and see if it works.

Comment: The machine is not part of a domain and the user is a local admin. The author name therefor is "OLDMACHINENAME\Administrator". The only way to edit the tasks (changes may have to be made in irregular intervals) right now is to rename the server back to its original name, reboot, edit the tasks, change the name again and reboot another time resulting in an undesired downtown of several minutes.